# Can I use although and but to connect 3 subsentences

Tags: american-english

My question is: is the following structure correct?
ALTHOUGH subsentence A, subsentence B, BUT subsentence C.

I know it's not correct to use "although and but" to connect 2 subsentences, but how about 3?

Comment: Hello, Sun. You need to provide an actual example. Most things can be made acceptable with forced context. 'I stayed with the car for hours, although the temptation was to try to make it to the nearest phone box ... but you already know all this.'